# How do you unmarshall a org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Schema in a wsimport generated stub

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've generated client side stubs from a WSDL that includes the following snippet

```
<s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element ref="s:schema"/>
        <s:any/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

I get back stubs which contain org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Schema variable instances. How do I unmarshall these? I am looking at JAXB's Unmarshaller as I suspect this is how to do it, but I haven't been able to piece it together yet.

Can anyone point me to an example.

Comment: Furthermore, I can confirm through soap messaging tools that responses do infact come back with a schema definition for the types used in the response.

Comment: Ok, this seems to deal with what are called 'payload schemas'.